# Get element position based on size using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a `draggable div` and a `droppale div`. I get the position of draggable div within the droppable using the following code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.ff').draggable({
            appendTo: "#pages",
            revert: "invalid"
        });
        $('#pages').droppable({
            accept: ".ff",
            drop: function (event, ui) {                    
                var x = ui.offset.left - $(this).offset().left;
                var y = ui.offset.top - $(this).offset().top;
            }
        });
    });
```

I need to save these coordinates, but saving the "relative position" I mean, when somebody loads the points (x,y) saved previusly but with a different screen resolution, different device, etc. the points must be in the same position.

So, how to get this "relative position"?

Comment: Could you provide a little more clarity? You want the upper-left corner of the `.ff` element as it relates to the entire page rather than the `#pages` element?

Comment: If so, I believe you're looking for `.offset()`: http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with the following formula:

```
var x = (dropped.offset.left - container.offset().left) / container.width
```

This (`x`) is the result that I save. Now, to recreate:

```
var left = (x * container.width) + container.offset().left;
```